# Does squash commit release Git LFS storage

Tags: git, git-lfs

Here is a question I find myself asking:

- If we know `git lfs` keeps full copies of every version of each binary file being tracked (AFAIK);
- And that one of our feature branch contains many edits to the same set of large binary files;
- Then, on squash and merge (eg. merge as a single commit) and deletion of this feature branch, do we finally release storages on remote repo?

(AFAIK `git lfs prune` should release local repo storage when binary files are no longer in used; does remote repo know to release storage when there isn't a reference to these older version of binary files?)

Comment: As of now, having tried my above approaches, I didn't see GitHub release the storage space as expected.

Answer (score 4):

[Answers](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3832#issuecomment-534114616) from `git-lfs` dev (emphasis mine):

> Whether an LFS-capable Git hosting provider releases unused objects when they're no longer referenced is **up to the individual hosting provider**. **GitHub doesn't by default**; you'd need to write in to support and ask them to delete the objects for you, or if you're using a GHES instance, you'd want to ask your administrator to delete them. For other hosting providers, you should ask them.

Comment: GitHub officially [says](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-git-large-file-storage#git-lfs-objects-in-your-repository) that we need to delete and recreate the repository or ask them to purge the unused objects.